Unable to update GML Multisurface after GeoServer upgrade
We are testing a (much needed) upgrade from GeoServer 2.17.2 to 2.25.1.  We are currently stumped as to why we can't seem to be able to update or insert a multisurface using the same WFS transaction as with 2.17.  I'm sure there is something simple we are missing here, so I'm hoping someone can point us in the right direction.
Here is an example transaction that is failing:
    <wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.1" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:MyWorkspace="http://mydomain.com/myworkspace">
    <wfs:Update typeName="MyWorkspace:MyLayer">
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>Item_Name</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value><![CDATA[Bob]]></wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <!--other properties-->
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>SHAPE</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>
                <gml:MultiSurface srsName='http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326'>
                    <gml:surfaceMembers>
                        <gml:Polygon>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>-92.6834743019173 35.2264426107788 -92.6830394566101 35.2264555548522 -92.68301875 35.2266209299999 -92.6834852899999 35.22663787 -92.6834743019173 35.2264426107788</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:Polygon>
                        <gml:Polygon>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>-92.6830420474193 35.2264347826591 -92.6827235345709 35.2264521083911 -92.68272353 35.2266102100001 -92.68301873 35.22662093 -92.6830420474193 35.2264347826591</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:Polygon>
                    </gml:surfaceMembers>
                </gml:MultiSurface>
            </wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <ogc:Filter>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>OBJECTID</PropertyName>
                <Literal><![CDATA[100832369]]></Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>

And here is what I feel is the relevant error logged in GeoServer:
ERROR  [geoserver.wfs] - Transaction failed
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Update error: Error occured updating features
...
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24114: The label MULTISURFACE (((-92. in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).

I have tried altering the WFS version and specifying GML version and even changing to using multipolygon instead of multisurface, but I'm to the point that I'm just shooting in the dark.
UPDATE
After enabling developer level logging, I also receive the following "Info" log:
    INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.1
    baseUrl = http://myurl:myport/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:update=net.opengis.wfs.impl.UpdateElementTypeImpl@2f8c1c44 (filter: [[ OBJECTID = 100832369 ]], handle: null, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null, typeName: {http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer)group[0] = wfs:delete=net.opengis.wfs.impl.DeleteElementTypeImpl@645e0daf (filter: [[ OBJECTID = 100832371 ]], handle: null, typeName: {http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer)
    update[0]:
        property[0]:
            ... several redacted properties and values ...
            name = SHAPE
            value = MULTIPOLYGON (((-92.6834743019173 35.2264426107788, -92.6830394566101 35.2264555548522, -92.68301875 35.2266209299999, -92.6834852899999 35.22663787, -92.6834743019173 35.2264426107788)), ((-92.6830420474193 35.2264347826591, -92.6827235345709 35.2264521083911, -92.68272353 35.2266102100001, -92.68301873 35.22662093, -92.6830420474193 35.2264347826591)))
        filter = [[ OBJECTID = 100832369 ]]
        inputFormat = x-application/gml:3
        typeName = {http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer
    delete[0]:
        filter = [[ OBJECTID = 100832371 ]]
        typeName = {http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer
    releaseAction = ALL
INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.

Very interesting that the geometry is already converted to multipolygon here.  Not sure why it isn't hitting SQL as a multipolygon.
UPDATE
For completeness, here is more of the stack trace from the log (I'm up against the body limit for characters in SO, so hopefully this is enough):
17 Jul 11:08:42 TRACE  [geoserver.requests] - First 4 bytes of XML doc are : 3C ('<') 77 ('w') 66 ('f') 73 ('s')
17 Jul 11:08:42 DEBUG  [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 1. Inferred encoding: UTF-8
17 Jul 11:08:42 TRACE  [geoserver.requests] - Invalid(?) XML declaration: <wfs:T.
17 Jul 11:08:42 DEBUG  [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 2. Charset in XML declaration is `null`.
17 Jul 11:08:42 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
<several geoserver.platform items>
17 Jul 11:08:42 DEBUG  [geoserver.wfs] - Locating FeatureSource uri:'http://myurl/myworkspace' name:'mylayer'
<several geoserver.platform items>
17 Jul 11:08:42 DEBUG  [geoserver.wfs] - located FeatureType w/ typeRef 'mystore:mylayer' and elementName '{http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer'
17 Jul 11:08:42 DEBUG  [geoserver.wfs] - Locating FeatureSource uri:'http://myurl/myworkspace' name:'mylayer'
<several geoserver.platform items>
17 Jul 11:08:42 DEBUG  [geoserver.wfs] - located FeatureType w/ typeRef 'mystore:mylayer' and elementName '{http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer'
17 Jul 11:08:42 TRACE  [geoserver.wfs] - Transaction Update:org.geoserver.wfs.request.Update$WFS11@74156385
17 Jul 11:08:42 TRACE  [geoserver.wfs] - Preprocess to remember modification as a set of fids
17 Jul 11:08:42 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {http://myurl/myworkspace}mylayer TransactionEventType[PreUpdate]
<several geoserver.platform items>
17 Jul 11:08:42 ERROR  [geoserver.wfs] - Transaction failed
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Update error: Error occured updating features
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionExceptionFactory.newWFSTransactionException(WFSTransactionExceptionFactory.java:37)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.UpdateElementHandler.execute(UpdateElementHandler.java:379)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction$BatchManager.runAggregated(Transaction.java:777)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction$BatchManager.run(Transaction.java:697)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:299)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:98)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor731.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.transaction(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor730.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:883)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured updating features
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.update(JDBCDataStore.java:2161)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.modifyFeatures(JDBCFeatureStore.java:374)
    at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingFeatureStore.modifyFeatures(RetypingFeatureStore.java:118)
    at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingFeatureStore.modifyFeatures(RetypingFeatureStore.java:93)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.global.GeoServerFeatureStore.modifyFeatures(GeoServerFeatureStore.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.UpdateElementHandler.execute(UpdateElementHandler.java:373)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24114: The label MULTISURFACE (((-92. in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisTypes.ParseLabel(String input)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1658)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:898)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:793)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:237)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:766)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.update(JDBCDataStore.java:2155)
    ... 123 more


It looks like the error is coming from mssql rather than the gml reader, can you turn logging up to developer and try again

Ian, thanks for responding!  I added some additional info from the developer logs.  There is certainly a lot more that displays now, but it feels like most of the rest is unrelated.

There isn't a WFS version 1.1.1, do you mean 1.1.0 or 2.0.0

Good catch, nmtoken.  However, changing it to 1.1.0 still results in the same issue and errors.

Can you add the stack trace to the error
